# AutoMapper - How to map entire object from source's single property?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Creating a map for two types where the destination type shares some of the source's properties is really straightforward:

```cs
CreateMap<Type1, Type2>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
```

But what if I have `Type1` inside other property? Let's call it - `ParentType`. Currently, I do this

```cs
CreateMap<ParentType, Type2>().IgnoreAllNonExisting()
  .ForMember(t => t.Prop1, opt => opt.MapFrom(l => l.Child.Prop1))
  .ForMember(t => t.Prop2, opt => opt.MapFrom(l => l.Child.Prop2))
  .ForMember(t => t.Prop3, opt => opt.MapFrom(l => l.Child.Prop3))
```

The `Child` property is of type `Type1`. Because of this, I have to map every property separately. Is there a better approach for such cases?

Comment: I would generally recommend to avoid AutoMapper because it makes it very difficult to refactor your application later and turns build-time problems into run-time problems. Once you get to a scenario like this where you need to manually write code to map each property, you're really writing more code than just writing a plain mapping function.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Answer (score 3):

As @Lucian already suggested, use `IncludeMembers(p => p.Child)` pointing to a child object which also should be used when mapping to destination object:

```cs
CreateMap<Type1, Type2>();
CreateMap<ParentType, Type2>()
    .IncludeMembers(p => p.Child);
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this solution did not work for me. Mapper acts as if this map didn't exist.